# Найти текст в строке и вырезать его

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$var = 'text text textidXXXXtext';
```

Как вырезать **idXXXX**, где **X** это цифры?

P.s: цифры всегда разные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php) (Заменяет все вхождения строки поиска на строку замены)

```
$result= str_replace('idXXXX', '',  $var);
```

Если цифры всегда разные, то поможет [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) (Выполняет поиск и замену по регулярному выражению)

```
$string = 'text text textid123text';
$pattern = '/(id\d+)/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: Прошу прощение, что не уточнила, что цифры всегда разные. Внесла изменение в вопрос

Comment: @Евгения добавил в ответ